# Submit button increasing amount of submissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that opens a modal that has a form with some selectors and then a submit button which triggers a confirmation box. (NOTE: the modal only opens if rows have been selected in a table via checkboxes). The functionality works as intended for the most part. I've noticed that if I exit the modal, change my selections in my table, re-click the button that opens the modal and click submit, the confirmation box pops up twice. If I close the modal and open it again, the confirmation box pops up three times, and so on. I'm not sure why it's doing this. (tables and selectors are created dynamically)

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Reassign Unit Button -->
<button id='reassign_unit_button'>Reassign Unit</button>

<!-- Reassign Unit Modal -->
<div id="reassignModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>Reassign Unit</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="reassign_unit_form">
                <label><strong>Office:&nbsp;</strong></label>
                <select id="reassign_unit_geo">
                </select>
                <label><strong>Customer:&nbsp;</strong></label>
                <select id="reassign_unit_customer">
                </select>
                <label><strong>Frimware:&nbsp;</strong></label>
                <select disabled='disabled' id="reassign_unit_fw">
                <option selected="selected" value="0">Select firmware version...</option>
                </select>
                <button id="submit_reassign" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document.ready(function() {
   var modal = document.getElementById('reassignModal');

   $('#reassign_unit_button').on('click', function() {
      if ($('.opt:checkbox:checked').length === 0) {
         alert('No units selected for reassignment. Please check the checkbox of the unit(s) you would like to reassign from the [Units Table].');
      } else {
         // code for selector listeners

         // When submit clicked
         $('#submit_reassign').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $units = $('.opt:checkbox:checked').length; //.opt class is on all checkboxes in table

            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to reassign ["+$units+"] units?")) {
               // Get all selected units
               $('.opt:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                  var $id = $(this).val();
                  var $mac = $('#customer_table_mac_'+$id).text();
                  $.ajax({
                     cache: false,
                     url:'reassign_unit.php',
                     method:'POST',
                     data:{
                        reassign_geo:$geo, //$geo, $cus, $fw, and $ver are set elsewhere
                        reassign_customer:$cus,
                        reassign_fw:$fw,
                        reassign_ver:$ver,
                        reassign_mac:$mac,
                     },
                     success: function(data) {
                        if (data !== '') { alert(data); }
                     },
                  });
               });
            }
         });
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Does this snippet of JavaScript execute more than once?  It sounds like there's more context than being shown here.

Comment: That's why I'm confused, as it is not. it is inside an if like so `if($('.opt:checkbox:checked').length === 0) { alert('need to make selection'); } else { <listeners for each selector> <js above> }`

Comment: I dont see that code at all

Comment: @jrod091: And where is that `if`?  Can you provide a more complete example?  The behavior sounds like the click handler is being attached multiple times.

Comment: just updated js code

Comment: Every time you click `#reassign_unit_button` another event handler is being added to `#submit_reassign`. Theres your problem.

Comment: I added `console.log($('.opt:checkbox:checked').length);` right after the `else` and also once inside the `if` inside the `.on('click')` and it only prints once inside the first log, but multiple times inside the `if` as described. I have no other loops in the code

Comment: You have two click events, which one you talkin about? Every time you click that button and you have something checked you are adding another event handler to `#submit_reassign`, hence why the alert keeps popping up more and more every time you click `#reassign_unit_button`. Just dont nest your handlers.

Comment: Do not bind events inside of events that can happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you click this:

```
$('#reassign_unit_button').on('click', function() {
```

What happens?  You do this:

```
$('#submit_reassign').on('click', function(event) {
```

So every time you click the "reassign unit button" you create a *new* click handler on the "submit reassign" button.  If you click the former button once, then the next time you click the latter button you will invoke that handler once.  When you click the former button again, the next time you click the latter button you will invoke the handler twice.  And so on.

Why do you need to assign the click handler inside of another click handler at all?  Just assign it once when the document loads.  Perhaps something like this:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
   $('#reassign_unit_button').on('click', function() {
      if ($('.opt:checkbox:checked').length === 0) {
         alert('No units selected for reassignment. Please check the checkbox of the unit(s) you would like to reassign from the [Units Table].');
      }
   });

   $('#submit_reassign').on('click', function(event) {
      // your existing click handler
   });

   // anything else you want to do when the document loads, etc.
});
```

There may be other logic in your overall application that you need to adjust as a result, I can't exactly debug outside of this context, but the idea itself should be clear.  Create your event listeners when the page loads and that's it, don't dynamically re-create them in your logic.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine: It even happened *immediately* upon posting the answer.  Less than a second had passed.  Hardly enough time to read a post.  But it's best not to take votes (up or down) personally, just try to help as best we can.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, but I definitely upvoted this answer. I believe this will work for me! Thank you for your answer! and thank you @IsaacVidrine for first pointing out the issue!